# Cheapest way to wake up multiple waiting threads without blocking

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, synchronization

I use boost::thread to manage threads. In my program i have pool of threads (workers) that are activated sometimes to do some job simultaneously.

Now i use boost::condition_variable: and all threads are waiting inside boost::condition_variable::wait() call on their own conditional_variableS objects.

Can i AVOID using mutexes in classic scheme, when i work with conditional_variables? I want to wake up threads, but don't need to pass some data to them, so don't need a mutex to be locked/unlocked during awakening process, why should i spend CPU on this (but yes, i should remember about spurious wakeups)?

The boost::condition_variable::wait() call trying to REACQUIRE the locking object when CV received the notification. But i don't need this exact facility.

What is cheapest way to awake several threads from another thread?

Answer (score 3):

If you don't reacquire the locking object, how can the threads know that they are done waiting? What will tell them that? Returning from the block tells them nothing because the blocking object is stateless. It doesn't have an "unlocked" or "not blocking" state for it to return in.

You have to pass some data to them, otherwise how will they know that before they had to wait and now they don't? A condition variable is completely stateless, so any state that you need must be maintained and passed by you.

One common pattern is to use a mutex, condition variable, and a state integer. To block, do this:

1. Acquire the mutex.
2. Copy the value of the state integer.
3. Block on the condition variable, releasing the mutex.
4. If the state integer is the same as it was when you coped it, go to step 3.
5. Release the mutex.

To unblock all threads, do this:

1. Acquire the mutex.
2. Increment the state integer.
3. Broadcast the condition variable.
4. Release the mutex.

Notice how step 4 of the locking algorithm tests whether the thread is done waiting? Notice how this code tracks whether or not there has been an unblock since the thread decided to block? You have to do that because condition variables don't do it themselves. (And that's why you need to reacquire the locking object.)

If you try to remove the state integer, your code will behave unpredictably. Sometimes you will block too long due to missed wakeups and sometimes you won't block long enough due to spurious wakeups. Only a state integer (or similar predicate) protected by the mutex tells the threads when to wait and when to stop waiting.

Also, I haven't seen how your code uses this, but it almost always folds into logic you're already using. Why did the threads block anyway? Is it because there's no work for them to do? And when they wakeup, are they going to figure out what to do? Well, finding out that there's no work for them to do and finding out what work they do need to do will require some lock since it's shared state, right? So there almost always is already a lock you're holding when you decide to block and need to reacquire when you're done waiting.

Comment: Thank you. But this is what i use now, but the problem is i don't want to spend CPU time on mutex lock/unlock. Oh... yes, spurious wakeups... I don't know too much about them. Will think.

Comment: Have you benchmarked? Because this is very close to optimum. Any mechanism that you use that doesn't make you do this will most likely be because that mechanism does exactly this internally, negating any possible savings.

Comment: Yes, played with VTune Amplifier XE 2011 today. Sometimes the parallel job is too short and threads awakening takes 20% of job's duration.

Comment: How can it be anywhere close to optimum when you wake up N threads to do some parallel work, and what they all do immediately is contend for the same mutex?

Comment: @Kaz: Because they usually wind up contending for the same mutex anyway. Presumably, the threads are related in some way, such as part of the same thread pool. So they generally wind up acquiring a lock to check on the pool's work queue. Having the waking/blocking algorithm understand that permits it to optimize the process. Rather than actually having them all wake up just to contend and go back to sleep, for example, it can use wait morphing to avoid a thundering herd. (That is, far from creating a thundering herd, this lets the implementation avoid one.)

Comment: The worker threads don't touch any shared resources during the job, so no any contending for some mutexes.

Comment: @pavelkolodin: Then what are they waiting for? (You should probably update your question and explain your actual situation in some detail.)

Comment: I've got some sympathy with @pavelkolodin position here.  The need to access some shared state after being signaled is not a lock, (!), even though very common.  I've seen all the stuff about spurious/missed wakeups before, but was never 100% convinced by any explanations.  Just the phrase 'spurious wakeup' to me means 'the OS does not work correctly'.  Some might say that the penguins who implemented boost on their beloved U**x realized that the problem could not be easily fixed & so documented it and moved the annoying workaround into user domain, but I could not possibly comment.

Comment: If the mutex lock is consistently taking 20% of the time, you should re-examine the granularity of your jobs.  It sounds like you have too many threads doing too fine-grained of jobs.

Comment: @MartinJames: It's a fundamental race condition. The only way to fix it is to use some kind of predicate to decide whether to wait or not. The issue is just who implements that predicate and where it is implemented. Condition variables are implemented as stateless primitives solely to give threads something to block on. There's almost always some shared state that made you decide to block anyway, and if not, you can trivially implement it as I showed above. But, of course, if condition variables aren't right for your problem (and they aren't best for everything), use something else.

Comment: @MartinJames:  "spurious wakeup" is found in the original pthreads spec.  Though its origins might be Unix-related, it likely has nothing to do with Linux per se -- and certainly nothing to do with boost (other than boost may be impl'ed using pthreads).

Comment: @mcmcc - thanks for the clarification.  It's like a bad smell in the kitchen - you may not know exactly where it's coming from, but it's definitely there!

Comment: @MartinJames: If you find a way to implement condition variables that are stateless but have no spurious wakeups, you will be hailed as a genius, since it's pretty close to provably impossible. (There is no way to know at the time the condition variable is signaled whether or not any thread will change the predicate before the thread you would unblock will check it. So deciding whether or not to wake a blocked thread requires predicting the future. You basically have to unblock and that wakeup might turn out to be spurious at the wakeup time.)

Answer (score 0):

For controlling threads doing parallel jobs, there is a nice primitive called a barrier.

A barrier is initialized with some positive integer value N representing how many threads it holds. A barrier has only a single operation: `wait`. When `N` threads call wait, the barrier releases all of them. Additionally, one of the threads is given a special return value indicating that it is the "serial thread"; that thread will be the one to do some special job, like integrating the results of the computation from the other threads.

The limitation is that a given barrier has to know the exact number of threads. It's really suitable for parallel processing type situations.

POSIX added barriers in 2003. A web search indicates that Boost has them, too.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_33_1/doc/html/barrier.html

Comment: I don't think there is any reliable way to wake up an unknown number of threads without any state due to the lost wakeup problem. Microsoft tried this many years ago in the form of a now-obsolescent function `PulseEvent`. This worked only in the cooperatively multitasked Windows 3. In cooperative tasking on a single CPU, a thread knows not only that it is the only one running, but that all the others are actually suspended inside the `yield` function. In other words, there `is` a big scheduling mutex in the system, and so `PulseEvent` is rather condition broadcast, referenced to that mutex.

Comment: 'wake up an unknown number of threads without any state' - I suspect that you are right, but it may be possible to wake up an unknown number of threads without those threads needing to read state after the wakeup.  How about a thread-count inside a Critical Section + a semaphore?  Threads needing to wait would enter the CS, increment the count, leave the CS and wait on the semaphore.  A thread that wants to signal enters the CS, signals [count] units to the semaphore, zeros the count and exits the CS.

Comment: @MartinJames: That will lead to spurious wakeups. Consider: There is no new work to do. Thread A blocks. Thread B queues some work and signals the condition variable, waking thread A. Thread C then finishes the work it was doing, checks the work queue, finds the work and pulls it from the queue. Finally, thread B wakes up and finds the work queue empty! Whoops, spurious wakeup. How do you fix this without senselessly forcing thread C to block and waiting until thread B wakes up to do the work -- a solution much worse than the problem. (Extra context switches, worse cache behavior, etc..)

Comment: @MartinJames: You're probably thinking that thread C shouldn't have changed the predicate without changing the state of the condition variable. But ... condition variables are stateless. The whole point of them is that the state is managed externally, by your code.

Comment: @MartinJames: The problem is that the threads which call the function, but have not reached the critical section yet are not yet counted, so they miss the wakeup signal.

Comment: @Kaz - sure!  Threads that have not elected to wait cannot be expected to receive a wakeup signal.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - what work queue?  Kaz did not mention any work queue.  I appreciate that condvars do not work for producer-consumer queues without a loop, but not all blocking requirements involve P-C queues.

Comment: @MartinJames: Sorry, I thought you were claiming you had a solution to the spurious wakeup problem in general. If that was intended as an answer to the OP's problem, you should post it as one. In any event, your solution would have analogous problems in his case, it just wouldn't be centered around a job queue. (One such problem would be the one Kaz pointed out.)

Comment: 'answer to the OP's problem, you should post it as one' - I would do, if I had tested it or was pretty sure of correct behaviour. Sadly, I'm only at the 'should work' state...

Answer (score 0):

**Generally speaking, you can't.**

Assuming the algorithm looks something like this:

```
ConditionVariable cv;

void WorkerThread()
{
  for (;;)
  {
    cv.wait();
    DoWork();
  }
}

void MainThread()
{
  for (;;)
  {
    ScheduleWork();
    cv.notify_all();
  }
}
```

NOTE:  I intentionally omitted any reference to mutexes in this pseudo-code.  For the purposes of this example, we'll suppose ConditionVariable does not require a mutex.

The first time through MainTnread(), work is queued and then it notifies WorkerThread() that it should execute its work.  At this point two things can happen:

1. WorkerThread() completes DoWork() before MainThread() can complete ScheduleWork().
2. MainThread() completes ScheduleWork() before WorkerThread() can complete DoWork().

In case #1, WorkerThread() comes back around to sleep on the CV, and is awoken by the next cv.notify() and all is well.

In case #2, MainThread() comes back around and notifies... **nobody** and continues on.  Meanwhile WorkerThread() eventually comes back around in its loop and waits on the CV but it is now one or more iterations behind MainThread().

This is known as a "lost wakeup".  It is similar to the notorious "spurious wakeup" in that the two threads now have different ideas about how many notify()s have taken place.  If you are expecting the two threads to maintain synchrony (and usually you are), you need some sort of shared synchronization primitive to control it.  This is where the mutex comes in.  It helps avoid lost wakeups which, arguably, are a more serious problem than the spurious variety.  Either way, the effects can be serious.

**UPDATE:**  For further rationale behind this design, see this comment by one of the original POSIX authors:  https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.programming.threads/cpJxTPu3acc/Hw3sbptsY4sJ

> Spurious wakeups are two things:
>
> - Write your program carefully, and make sure it works even if you
>      missed something.
> - Support efficient SMP implementations
>
> There may be rare cases where an "absolutely, paranoiacally correct"
>   implementation of condition wakeup, given simultaneous wait and
>   signal/broadcast on different processors, would require additional
>   synchronization that would slow down ALL condition variable operations
>   while providing no benefit in 99.99999% of all calls. Is it worth the
>   overhead? No way!
>
> But, really, that's an excuse because we wanted to force people to
>   write safe code. (Yes, that's the truth.)

Answer (score 0):

boost::condition_variable::notify_*(lock) does **NOT** require that the caller hold the lock on the mutex. THis is a nice improvement over the Java model in that it decouples the notification of threads with the holding of the lock.

Strictly speaking, this means the following pointless code SHOULD DO what you are asking:

```
lock_guard lock(mutex);
// Do something
cv.wait(lock);
// Do something else


unique_lock otherLock(mutex);
//do something
otherLock.unlock();
cv.notify_one();
```

I do not believe you need to call otherLock.lock() first.